# How do I resolve Failed to convert @drawable/abc into a drawable?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been going through an online Android tutorial by

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_intents_filters.htm

and getting the error while doing activity_main.xml file changes as per the instruction in the tutorial the error is like this

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/abc')
```

My android studio version is 2.2.3 and its running on windows 10 64 bit.

Acticity_main.xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/abc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Error details

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/abc' must start with #
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getColor(ResourceHelper.java:87)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:356)
at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getDrawable(BridgeTypedArray.java:695)
at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:157)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:84)
at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:80)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:60)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:56)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:465)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:172)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:150)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:193)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:333)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:152)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:222)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:324)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:389)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:548)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:966)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:533)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$70(RenderTask.java:659)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried clean/invalid-cache as I found in google search but still stuck in this error. All the part in this online tutorial have this in code but not mentioned any error in site.

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Do you have a resource named abc in your drawable folder..?

Comment: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/abc' must start with #`. Double check you have placed drawable in `drawable` folder, colors in `colors.xml`.

Comment: For those learning with Tutorials points: "abc" refers to their logo: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_alert_dialoges.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
check your  drawable folder "abc.png"(image) file is present or not.
```

Comment: Yes there was nothing in drawable folder I created a png file with name and the error disappear , but now I got a new one

Comment: The value is Settings. It serves to you to compose your layouts. Is created by default on Eclipse.

<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

Comment: check /app/src/main/res/values/string.xml  file

Comment: Where should I make these changes ?

Comment: string.xml file add <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136732/discussion-between-santosh-bachkar-and-gopipuli).

Answer (score 2):

If you have some vectorial or png file in the drawable folders the resourse has to be found. If your abc resource is a color, then you should reference it with `@color/abc` instead of `@drawable/abc`. I say this only because you have this first line in the stack trace which says:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Color value '@drawable/abc' must start with #
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a drawable file by the name abc.xml in

> \app\src\main\res\drawable

directory in order to use it. 
To add a vector asset as a drawable to your project

> expand res right click on drawable
>
> New
>
> Vector Asset click on android icon fron the window and choose an icon
>   from the list
>
> OK
>
> rename it to abc OR just change the src property of your ImageButton
>   in layout to the name of the drawable.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a xml file in order to be placed in the drawable folder.. it could be a common image too.

Comment: Yes of course. But a .png or .jpeg image takes more space. Also google encourage developers to use vector assets as they are salable and follow material design specifications suggested by google. But if you want to display an image then you can simply paste it in drawable folder and can use it as any other drawable.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error.

The solution is to have an image(i used png) file.
Copy the image file to your `/res/drawable` folder.
Update the `activity_main.xml` file to reference your new filename without the extension.

Example:

```
/res/drawable/nemo.png
```

In the activity_main, changed to:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@drawable/nemo"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```